# In Seaborn, can a particular color override hue which is already on the basis on another column?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot in seaborn such that hue defines my data points on the basis of one column and if another column value is 1, that should override the hue.

This I am doing for anomaly detection in K means, so I plot hue for different clusters, which is fine, but now in that same plot, if the row has "anomaly" column=1, then that data point, I want to show in red. Is this possible?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
                    'var2': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700], 
                    'cluster': [0,0,0,0,0,1,1], 'anomalies':[1,1,1,0,0,0,0]})
sns.scatterplot(x='var1', y='var2', hue='cluster', data=df)
```

eg. in the above code, somehow I should be able to pass custom colour according to label1 values
Expected: I should be able to plot hue on the basis of one column and custom colour on the basis of another column

Edit: Since @ImportanceOfBeingErnest asked the reason to use seaborn instead of matplotlib, I wanted to use seaborn instead of matplotlib since the plots are cleaner. eg.
[image: matplotlib]

[image: seaborn]

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `k-means` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: I guess you want to introduce one additional hue, in this case `[2,2,2,0,0,1,1]`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest but where do i add this additional hue?

Comment: In a column named "mycolumn" and use it as `hue = "mycolumn"`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 
sorry i didn't quite get it .. lets say for the example i gave above, 
sns.scatterplot(x='var1', y='var2', hue='cluster', data=df)
Now cluster column provides hue. But how do i make sure for the columns for which anomalies='1', it overrides the hue . So that anomalies i can show in red color and rest of the data defined by hue

Comment: Seems too complicated. I provided an easy solution below.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use matplotlib, it could look like this. Creating one scatter for the anomalies and one scatter for the rest.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
                    'var2': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700], 
                    'cluster': [0,0,0,0,0,1,1], 'anomalies':[1,1,1,0,0,0,0]})

plt.style.use("seaborn-whitegrid")
cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(256, as_cmap=True)

sc1 = plt.scatter(x='var1', y='var2', c='cluster', data=df[df['anomalies'] == 0], cmap=cmap)
sc2 = plt.scatter(x='var1', y='var2', color="red", data=df[df['anomalies'] == 1])  

h, l = sc1.legend_elements()
plt.legend(h+[sc2], l+["anomalies"])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for two matplotlibs scatter plot. But I wanted to have hue property of seaborn. Was able to solve using seaborn and then matplotlib in my answer.

Comment: There is no difference between the `hue` in seaborn and just plotting a scatter with the classes in matplotlib.

Comment: yeah you are right, hue is same as c in matplotlib, but matplotlib's plots are not as clean as seaborn, so wanted to use seaborn for that purpose

Comment: What is not clean about matplotlib's plots?

Comment: since I couldn't add image in the comment section, so I have updated the question with the images, which shows that seaborn plots are much cleaner than matplotlib . Thats why I wanted to use seaborn

Comment: That's a matter of choosing the right colormap, right? Something like `cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(256, as_cmap=True)` should give the same colors in matplotlib.

Comment: For the rest `plt.style.use("seaborn-whitegrid")` would give you the visual appearance.

Comment: tried both of these, didn't know seaborn could be included in matplotlib as well. nice to see this. But both of these didn't work together. Hence, was not able to get that beauty in the plot which seaborn provides using both of these techniques you mentioned above.
Is there a way in matplotlib so that we can apply these both and get the same plot as seaborn provides? Since most of the functionality is by matplotlib and seaborn is a wrapper on top of this, so if seaborn is able to do this, I guess matplotlib should also be able to apply both these

Answer (score 0):

As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest suggested, this could be achieved using two matplotlibs , but problem there is , I can't use hue property provided by seaborn.
Hence, to get the hue property of seaborn, I wanted to solve it using seaborn itself. Finally with some trial and error, I was able to solve this by combining seaborn and matplotlib in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(19,4))

df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
                    'var2': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700], 
                    'cluster': [0,0,0,0,0,1,1], 'anomalies':[1,0,1,0,0,0,0]})

sns.scatterplot(x='var1', y='var2', hue='cluster', data=df)
plt.scatter(x='var1', y='var2', color="red", data=df[df['anomalies'] == 1])

# plot the legend
legend = plt.legend()
legend.get_texts()[0].set_text("")
legend.get_texts()[3].set_text('anomaly')
```

So, after applying hue in scatterplot, I could use matplotlib to override only specific data in the plot and apply those specific colour to those data points